# Sleepy or hungry at salaat

Tags: salat

I had uncertainty till now,

In my memory, (I forget who said it or from which one I read about it), it will be safe to eat first or sleep first when we feel one of them before salaat.

Is sleepy or hungry at salaat will cancel salaat itself??

Thanks, 
Ahmad

Comment: For more infrmation see this please: http://muttaqun.com/aboutsalah.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hadith of the Prophet, peace be upon him, where he is reported to have said:

> لا صلاة بحضرة الطعام ولا وهو يدافع الاخبثين <sup>[[Muslim 560](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/5/84)]</sup>
>   *(rough translation: "There is no prayer while food is present, or while one is withholding the call of nature.")*

So we can conclude that the Prophet, peace be upon him, prohibited:

1. Praying in the state of **hunger while food is present**
2. Praying while one is **distracted by holding in urine and/or faeces**.

This hadith doesn't mention anything about prayer while tired.