# Can a person stop the undigested wastes inside him and in that condition is it correct to offer the prayer?

Tags: salat, practical-islam, wudu

Sometimes, after making wudu for salat and come from the bathroom, then suddenly I feel uncomfortable because my body wants to waste off undigested food from it. But I can not go again because I am in a wuzu condition and I prefer to offer the prayer and then go to bathroom. Is it does not affect my salat? Can a person offer the prayer in that condition?

Comment: Related: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8652/sleepy-or-hungry-at-salaat/8678?r=SearchResults#8678